# Is there an Ax-Grothendieck result for entire functions?

Tags: complex-geometry, model-theory, several-complex-variables

The Ax-Grothendieck result states that any polynomial injective function from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to itself is surjective. Is there such a statement for entire functions ?

Comment: I think Picard's theorem prevents such a result for $n=1$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29758/entire-1-1-function for the case n=1. They are not only surjective, they are even linear.

Comment: @Julien: do you have an explicit counter example for $n=1$ ?

Comment: @HeinrichD. Thx.

Comment: @Yoyo .The answer is no.The key words are Fatou-Bieberbach domains.